# Ayuda con estas lineas en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hola necesito ayuda con estas lineas me da error y no se el motivo. Primero la linea:

```
$registro = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE nomb_prod LIKE '%$dato%' OR tipo_prod LIKE '%$dato%' ORDER BY id_prod ASC");
```

Me da el siguiente error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   C:\wamp\www\www\registro\php\busca_producto.php on line 9

Otra linea que me da error:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($registro)>0){
    while($registro2 = mysql_fetch_array($registro)){
        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$registro2['nomb_prod'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['tipo_prod'].'</td>
                <td>S/. '.$registro2['precio_unit'].'</td>
                <td>S/. '.$registro2['precio_dist'].'</td>
                <td>'.fechaNormal($registro2['fecha_reg']).'</td>
                <td><a href="javascript:editarProducto('.$registro2['id_prod'].');" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></a> <a href="javascript:eliminarProducto('.$registro2['id_prod'].');" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></a></td>
                </tr>';
    }
}
```

En este caso el error es porque tengo que añadir un parametro. Bueno es simplemente que estoy mudando de mysql a mysqli que es bastante similar

Fichero conexion:

```
<?php

const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
const DB_USER = 'root';
const DB_PASSWORD = '';
const DB_NAME = 'tienda';
const DB_CHARSET = 'UTF8';

function database_connect()
{
    $conexion=new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
    if($conexion->connect_errno){
        echo "No conectado";
    }else{

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: El error parece indicar correctamente cuál es el problema. `mysqli_query` necesita dos parámetros, tú sólo pasaste uno

Comment: recupero la pregunta

Answer (score 3):

La definición del error viene en la propia descripción: le estás pasando un parámetro cuando le deberías pasar dos.

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\www\registro\php\busca_producto.php on line 9

Esto es así porque estás usando la versión procedimental de [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) en lugar de la versión orientada a objetos, entonces el primer parámetro debe ser la conexión a la base de datos y el segundo la consulta que quieras realizar:

```
$registro = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE nomb_prod LIKE '%$dato%' OR tipo_prod LIKE '%$dato%' ORDER BY id_prod ASC");
```

Donde `$conexion` será la variable que contiene tu conexión a la base de datos.

Comment: aunque le pongo el parametro de la conexion me da el error

Comment: por ejemplo pongo esto mysqli_query($database_connection,"INSERT ...) me da error

Comment: $registro = mysqli_query($database_connection,"SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY id_prod ASC");
esta me sigue dando el mismo error Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\wamp\www\www\registro\php\agrega_producto.php on line 27

Comment: ¿De qué es la conexión? Debería ser mysqli, pero parece que no lo es (¿estás usando `myqsl_*` para la conexión?)

Comment: esta todo bien hecho la conexion y todo

Comment: te pongo el fichero conexion a lo mejor se me paso algun detalle

Comment: Estás usando la conexión orientada a objetos y luego la consulta en modo procedimental. **Sé consistente**: o lo uno o lo otro. Solución rápida: `$registro = $conexion->("SELECT * FROM ....")`

Comment: @OmarAlami Si esta respuesta solucionó la pregunta original, márcala como aceptada, dándole al ✓ que hay en la parte superior izquierda.

Comment: no puedo hacer eso tampoco . lo intente y no funciono, gracias alvaro por tu ayuda

Comment: en pdo funciona pero como mysqli es mas parecido a mysql lo estoy intentando en msqli

Comment: Perdón, el código sería `$registro = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM ....")`

Comment: creo que voy a volver a PDO porque no me va

Comment: te voy a dar un voto positivo por tu ayuda y porque te lo mereces me quedo con pdo pa toda la vida hasta lo quiten saludo y gracias

Comment: @OmarAlami si esta es la respuesta que te ayudó a resolver el problema o gran parte del mismo, por favor acéptala. Puedes revisar cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas aquí: [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/427/227)

Comment: me pasado toda una tarde para una tonteria como una montaña cuando PDO es mil veces que msqli en mi opinion

Comment: Y luego de que te hayas pasado toda la tarde @OmarAlami, en 1 hora hubo una respuesta que te ayudó a solucionar tu problema. Quizás deberías **[✓ ACEPTARLA](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/427/127)** (y si no te parece, seguro alguna de tus otras [30+ preguntas](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/4456/omar-alami?tab=questions) tienen una respuesta que merece ser aceptada)... ¿Sabías que **se ganan** puntos al aceptar? Y si hay algo que no se entienda, bienvenido a preguntar en el [chat]

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar el problema, edita tu pregunta y añades la línea del error que código se encuentra.

Para realizar una consulta en la base de datos debes añadir la conexión caso contrario te mostrar errores.

Remplaza:

```
$registro = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE nomb_prod LIKE '%$dato%' OR tipo_prod LIKE '%$dato%' ORDER BY id_prod ASC");
```

Por:

```
$registro = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE nomb_prod LIKE '%$dato%' OR tipo_prod LIKE '%$dato%' ORDER BY id_prod ASC");
```

> **Nota** La variable `$conexion` obtiene los parametros todos los datos que contiene la conexión a la base de datos sin ella no obtendras resultado en tu consulta mostrandote errores.

Leer estos dos temas sobre realizar consultas con mysqli

- [Consulta mysqli paso a paso](http://www.phperos.net/foro/index.php?topic=9239.0)
- [Consulta mysqli orientado a objetos](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)

Observa detalladamente en la documentación que se añade siempre la variable de la conexión para realizar consultas de los registros en la base de datos.

**Ejemplo:**

Creo la conexión de la base de datos.

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "world");

/* comprobar la conexión */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}
```

La variable `$mysqli` obtendra los parametros o los datos de la conexión a la base de datos.

Ahora la consulta de los registros en la base de datos:

```
   $consulta = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) {

    /* obtener el array de objetos */
    while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_row()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $fila[0], $fila[1]);
    }

    /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */
    $resultado->close();
}

/* cerrar la conexión */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Revisando este código encontré un error a simple vista.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($registro)>0){
    while($registro2 = mysql_fetch_array($registro)){
        echo '';
    }
}
```

El error esta aquí  `mysql_fetch_array` debes revisar el código cuidadosamente para ver estos fallos o alguna línea u parametro o variable mal escrita.

> **Nota:** Al actualizar mysql a mysqli debes cambiar correctamente a todo el código a mysqli sin excepciones.

En vez de `mysql_fetch_array` reamplazar por `mysqli_fetch_array`  o por `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Te recomiendo leer esta [documentanción](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Saludos.